# Can I use iPadian as an iPad emulator for website development?

Tags: ios-simulator, emulation

I'm not sure if it's accurate or not.

For iPhone/iPad, I don't want to buy one and I don't feel like switching to Mac either. iPhone/iPad emulator is a big problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wildly old thread, but having the same issue myself.

I'm trying Ipadian but not really liking the results.

Probably better, I would recommend getting virtualbox and installing MacOSX, then open the contents of XCODE directory and there is an iOS emulator. That should work very well/accurate.

Also there is browserstack, but that costs money.